# Trying to delete blank rows and keep JSON rows in data frame

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

This is very, very weird, but I'm guessing there is a simple solution...I just haven't found it yet.  I am trying to delete all blank rows from a data frame, and keep all rows with data.  Here is my setup.

```
26                                                  []
27                                                  []
28                                                  []
29                                                  []
..                                                 ...
270  [{'id': 360014322992, 'default': True, 'name':...
271  [{'id': 360014322992, 'default': True, 'name':...
272  [{'id': 360014322992, 'default': True, 'name':...
```

Ultimately, I want to get to this.

```
df1 = [{'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'Production', 'raw_name': 'Production', 'value': 'production'}, {'id': 3600, 'default': False, 'name': 'Development', 'raw_name': 'Development', 'value': 'development'}, {'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'Staging', 'raw_name': 'Staging', 'value': 'staging'}]
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(df1), orient='columns')
print(df2)
```

However, that doesn't work for rows that have only `[]`  characters.  How can I delete rows with only `[]` or how can I code this to ignore the `[]` characters and normalize this data frame?  TIA.

When I try this:

```
df2 = df1[~df1.astype(bool)]
print(df2)
```

I get this:

```
28                    []
29                    []
..                   ...
270                  NaN
271                  NaN
```

When I try this:

```
df2 = df1[df1 != '[]']
print(df2)
```

I get this:

```
28                                                  []
29                                                  []
..                                                 ...
270  [{'id': 360014322992, 'default': True, 'name':...
271  [{'id': 360014322992, 'default': True, 'name':...
```

When I try this:

```
df2 = df1[df1.astype(bool)]
print(df2)
```

I get this:

```
28                                                 NaN
29                                                 NaN
..                                                 ...
270  [{'id': 360014322992, 'default': True, 'name':...
271  [{'id': 360014322992, 'default': True, 'name':...
```

I still can't normalize the JSON in the data frame!!

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd.io.json.json_normalize(df2), orient='columns')
print(df2)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
a = [{'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'Production', 'raw_name': 'Production', 'value': 'production'}, {'id': 3600, 'default': False, 'name': 'Development', 'raw_name': 'Development', 'value': 'development'}, 
     {'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'Staging', 'raw_name': 'Staging', 'value': 'staging'}]
```

---

```
s = pd.Series([[],[],a,a, np.nan])
print(s)
0                                                   []
1                                                   []
2    [{'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'Prod...
3    [{'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'Prod...
4                                                  NaN

#remove values with `NaN`s and empty lists
s1 = s[s.astype(bool) & s.notnull()]
print (s1)
2    [{'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'Prod...
3    [{'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'Prod...
dtype: object

#flatten values with DataFrame constructor 
df = pd.DataFrame([y for x in s1 for y in x])
print (df)
   default     id         name     raw_name        value
0    False  36001   Production   Production   production
1    False   3600  Development  Development  development
2    False  36001      Staging      Staging      staging
3    False  36001   Production   Production   production
4    False   3600  Development  Development  development
5    False  36001      Staging      Staging      staging
```

Another solution with removing missing values only by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([y for x in s.dropna() for y in x])
print (df)
   default     id         name     raw_name        value
0    False  36001   Production   Production   production
1    False   3600  Development  Development  development
2    False  36001      Staging      Staging      staging
3    False  36001   Production   Production   production
4    False   3600  Development  Development  development
5    False  36001      Staging      Staging      staging
```

Another idea - filter only lists:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([y for x in s[[isinstance(x, list) for x in s]] for y in x])
```

Comment: Thanks for the look jezrael.  I just updated my original post.  I'm stuck here.  This seems so simple, but nothing that I have tried has actually worked.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Try `df = df1[df1.astype(bool)]`, no `~`

Comment: Still throwing errors.  I just updated my original post.

Comment: No, none of that works.  Ugh!  I'm back to this: df2 = df1[df1.astype(bool)]
print(df2)


df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd.io.json.json_normalize(df2), orient='columns')
print(df2)

That gives me this error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: @ryguy72 - how working `df = pd.DataFrame([y for x in s[[isinstance(x, list) for x in s]] for y in x])` ?

Comment: I just tried that and I get this: ValueError: Item wrong length 29 instead of 301.  There are 301 rows in the data frame.  It looks like this: 0                                                   []
1                                                   []
2                                                   []
3                                                   []

...

298  [{'id': 360014322992, 'default': True, 'name':...
299  [{'id': 360014322992, 'default': True, 'name':...
300  [{'id': 360014322992, 'default': True, 'name':...

Comment: Everything comes from a google cloud table. I'm pulling the data into python, trying to parse it, and push everything to another google cloud table. I can pull the data down and push a sample that i created to the final table, but I can't parse the actual data and I can't push it into the final table as it is now.  Ugh!!

Comment: @ryguy72 - Hard to know, I am no your real data, so it is not easy find solution. Another one `df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in s.dropna()])`

Comment: I just tried the last one and got this: ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: It's almost like I need to drop rows with charterers like [].  There are a bunch of spaces in front of the square brackets.

Comment: I guess these are not real NAs.  I imagine that's the problem.

Comment: @ryguy72 Are data confidental?

Comment: Well, no, but you can't access it.  I'm querying a database behind a firewall.  I just tried to represent the scenario as best I could.

Comment: You know what, I finally got it working.  I ended up going with this: 
# create NAN
df = s[s.astype(bool)]
print(df)

# filter out 'NAN'
filtered_df = df[df['custom_field_options'].notnull()]
print(filtered_df)